# Using Common Delegate to call multiple methods across different classes

Tags: c#, delegates

I need to pass a delegate and a method name that the delegate should invoke as an argument to a class constructor how do i do this ??

i.e if

```
public delegate object CCommonDelegate();
```

is my delegate and say it can call any methods following this signature

```
string Method1();

object Method2();

class X
{
    public X(CCommonDelegate,"MethodName to invoke"){}  //how to pass the Method name here..

}
```

P.S : Ignore the access modifiers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A delegate is a variable that holds something that can be called. If `X` is a class that needs to be able to call something, then all it needs is the delegate:

```
public delegate object CommonDelegate();

class X
{
    CommonDelegate d;

    public X(CommonDelegate d)
    {
        this.d = d; // store the delegate for later
    }
}
```

Later it can call the delegate:

```
var o = d();
```

By the way, you don't need to define such a delegate. The type `Func<Object>` already exists and has the right structure.

To construct X given your two example methods:

```
string Method1()
object Method2()
```

You could say

```
var x = new X(obj.Method2);
```

Where `obj` is an object of the class that has `Method2`. In C# 4 you can do the same for `Method1`. But in 3 you'll need to convert using a lambda:

```
var x = new X(() => obj.Method1);
```

This is because the return type is not exactly the same: it's related by inheritance. This will only work automatically in C# 4, and only if you use `Func<object>`.

Comment: Will i be able to make Asynchronous calls using this ?

Comment: You can `BeginInvoke` on any delegate to start it executing on the thread pool. Whether you should is another matter! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

why not just have your constructor take an [Func< object>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

```
public class x
{
     public x(Func<object> func)
     {
           object obj = func();
     }
}
```

then

```
x myX = new x(()=> "test");
```